# Pythonの特殊メソッド iter ではクラスのオブジェクトも引数として取る事が可能？

Tags: python, python3

Pythonの特殊メソッド `iter` について、以下のコード例を見かけました。

[【Python入門】クラス利用時の特殊メソッド一覧（サンプルコード付き）](https://blog.codecamp.jp/python-class-code)

> ```
> class ITER():
>   def __init__(self, max = 0):
>       self.max = max
>
>   def __iter__(self):
>       self.n = 0
>       return self
>
>   def __next__(self):
>       if self.n <= self.max:
>           result = 2 ** self.n
>           self.n += 1
>           return result
>       else:
>           raise StopIteration
>
> x = ITER(2)
> i = iter(x)
> print(next(i))
> print(next(i))
> print(next(i))
> ```

`iter()` には引数として配列やタプルが入る思っていたのですが、クラスのオブジェクトも引数として取る事が可能なのでしょうか？

Comment: この辺の記事が@OOPerさん回答と同様の内容から、もう少し広げた分野までも扱っているようです。[イテラブル, iterable ってなに？](https://python.ms/iterable/), [PythonのIterableを順に追っていく](https://qiita.com/knknkn1162/items/17f7f370a2cc27f812ee), [Pythonのイテレータとジェネレータ](https://qiita.com/tomotaka_ito/items/35f3eb108f587022fa09)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pythonには、iterable という概念があり、`iter()`の(第一)引数には 任意のiterableなクラスのオブジェクトを渡すことができます。

あなたが挙げた配列やタプルは組み込みのiterableなオブジェクトの代表例ですが、iterableでさえあれば、自作のクラスを渡すこともできます。

[iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable)

> An object capable of returning its members one at a time. Examples of iterables include all sequence types (such as list, str, and tuple) and some non-sequence types like dict, file objects, and objects of any classes you define with an `__iter__()` method or with a `__getitem__()` method that implements Sequence semantics.

原文は少し説明が分かりにくいですが、

- `__iter__()`メソッドが定義されている. (かつそれが、iterator を返す.)

または、

- `__getitem__()`メソッドが定義されており、Sequence のセマンティックスを実装している.

ような任意のクラスのオブジェクトはiterableであるとされています。

あなたが見つけられた`ITER`クラスは、この1つ目のルール「`__iter__()`メソッドが定義されている. (かつそれが、itertor を返す.)」にマッチしているのでiterableであり、そのため`iter()`に渡すことができるわけです。

---

ちなみにiterableなオブジェクトは、for-inにもそのまま使えたり、アンパックもできたりします。

```
# `ITER`の定義は同じとする
x = ITER(2)
for i in x:
  print(i)

a, b, c = x
print(a, b, c)
```